# Vectorization with subset()?

Tags: r, vectorization, subset

I have a data frame of `scores` (`V3`) for a series of integer ranges (`V1` to `V2`).

```
scores <- structure(list(V1 = c(2037651L, 2037659L, 2037677L, 2037685L, 
  2037703L, 2037715L), V2 = c(2037700L, 2037708L, 2037726L, 2037734L, 
  2037752L, 2037764L), V3 = c(1.474269, 1.021012, 1.180993, 1.717131, 
  2.361985, 1.257013)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -6L))

    V1      V2      V3
1 2037651 2037700 1.474269
2 2037659 2037708 1.021012
3 2037677 2037726 1.180993
4 2037685 2037734 1.717131
5 2037703 2037752 2.361985
6 2037715 2037764 1.257013
```

I also have a vector of integers.

```
 coords <- structure(list(V1 = c(2037652, 2037653, 2037654, 2037655, 2037656, 
 2037657, 2037658, 2037659, 2037660, 2037661, 2037662, 2037663, 
 2037664, 2037665, 2037666, 2037667, 2037668, 2037669, 2037670, 
 2037671)), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

For each integer (in `coords`), I would like to determine the average of all scores (in `scores$V3`) whose  integer range (scores `V1` to `V2`) contains `coord$V1`. To accomplish this, I tried:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(coord)){
    range_scores <- subset(scores, 
                           scores$V1 <= coord$V1[i] & scores$V2 >= coord$V1[i])
    coord$V2[i] <- mean(range_scores$V3)
}
```

The function works, but is extremely slow.

How can I accomplish the same thing more efficiently?

Comment: Do you mean `coords$V` or `coords$V1`?

Comment: I think you may want to use cut to make a new column and then a split lapply combo but it's difficult to surmise precisely what you're after.

Comment: I do not get the same output that you get when I use your code. My solution would be: `coord$V2 <- sapply(coord$V1, function(x) mean(scores[scores[, 2] > x & x >  scores[, 1], 3]))`.  Then I get the output you show, but it's 4 times slower than yours :-( (when I use your for loop, all V2 are 1.474269)

Comment: I just posted a similar code and then I saw your comment and I deleted my code. Although sapply and lapply are still loop but I thought that they deal with data more efficiently and should be faster! I wonder why you are saying it's 4 times slower?

Comment: Sorry. I initially made `coord` a vector, so I had to change `nrow` to `length` and I forgot to change it back when I made `coord` a `data.frame`.  Now, it looks like it is a little faster to use `sapply`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my proposed solution:

```
scores = read.table(header=FALSE,
                    text="2037651 2037700 1.474269
                          2037659 2037708 1.021012
                          2037677 2037726 1.180993
                          2037685 2037734 1.717131
                          2037703 2037752 2.361985
                          2037715 2037764 1.257013")

coord = data.frame(V1=c(2037652, 2037653, 2037654, 2037655, 2037656, 2037657,
                     2037658, 2037659, 2037660, 2037661, 2037662, 2037663,
                     2037664, 2037665, 2037666, 2037667, 2037668, 2037669,
                     2037670, 2037671))

coord_vec = coord$V1                  # Store as a vector instead of data.frame
scores_mat = as.matrix(scores)        # Store as a matrix instead of data.frame
results = numeric(length=nrow(coord)) # Pre-allocate vector to store results.

for (i in 1:nrow(coord)) {
    select_rows = ((scores_mat[, 1] <= coord_vec[i]) & 
                   (scores_mat[, 2] >= coord_vec[i]))
    scores_subset = scores_mat[select_rows, 3] # Use logical indexing.
    results[i] = mean(scores_subset)
}
results
#  [1] 1.474269 1.474269 1.474269 1.474269 1.474269 1.474269 1.474269 1.247641
#  [9] 1.247641 1.247641 1.247641 1.247641 1.247641 1.247641 1.247641 1.247641
# [17] 1.247641 1.247641 1.247641 1.247641

# Benchmark results using @GSee's code. Needs library(rbenchmark).
#        test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
# 4 bdemarest          100   0.046 1.000000     0.046    0.001
# 2      gsee          100   0.170 3.695652     0.170    0.001
# 1      orig          100   0.358 7.782609     0.360    0.001
# 3    sepehr          100   0.163 3.543478     0.164    0.000
```

It seems quite a bit faster than the other proposals. I'm pretty sure the advantage is gained by avoiding reading from or writing to a data.frame (a high-overhead function). Also, I use logical indexing instead of `subset()` to further reduce overhead. Possibly it could be made faster by using a *ply strategy?

Comment: thanks everyone for your responses. these solutions work great, and I ended up using bdemarest's solution. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

`coord$V2 <- sapply(coord$V1, function(x) mean(scores[scores[, 2] >= x & x >=  scores[, 1], 3]))` is about twice as fast.

First, recreate your data:

```
scores <- read.table(text="       V1      V2      V3
1 2037651 2037700 1.474269
2 2037659 2037708 1.021012
3 2037677 2037726 1.180993
4 2037685 2037734 1.717131
5 2037703 2037752 2.361985
6 2037715 2037764 1.257013", row.names=1)

coord <-data.frame(V1=c(2037652, 2037653, 2037654, 2037655, 2037656, 2037657, 2037658, 
           2037659, 2037660, 2037661, 2037662, 2037663, 2037664, 2037665, 
           2037666, 2037667, 2037668, 2037669, 2037670, 2037671))
```

Make functions and benchmark:

```
gsee <- function(coord) {
    coord$V2 <- sapply(coord$V1, function(x) mean(scores[scores[, 2] >= x & x >=  scores[, 1], 3]))
    coord
}

orig <- function(coord) {
    for(i in 1:NROW(coord)){
        range_scores<-subset(scores, scores$V1 <= coord$V1[i] & scores$V2 >= coord$V1[i]);
        coord$V2[i]<-mean(range_scores$V3)
    }
    coord
}
identical(gsee(coord), orig(coord))  # TRUE
benchmark(orig=orig(coord), gsee=gsee(coord))

test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2 gsee          100   0.175 1.000000     0.175    0.000          0         0
1 orig          100   0.379 2.165714     0.377    0.002          0         0
```

---

Edit: 
`lapply` per @Sepehr is marginally better.

```
sepehr <- function(coord) {
    coord$V2 <- unlist(lapply(coord$V1, function(x) mean(scores[scores[, 2] >= x & x >=  scores[, 1], 3])))
    coord
}
benchmark(orig=orig(coord), gsee=gsee(coord), sepehr=sepehr(coord))
test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2   gsee          100   0.171 1.023952     0.171    0.000          0         0
1   orig          100   0.369 2.209581     0.369    0.001          0         0
3 sepehr          100   0.167 1.000000     0.167    0.000          0         0
```

Comment: Interesting. I think sapply has one additional step compared to  lapply and that is converting a list output into a vector and perhaps that causes the difference. Thanks,